# Exercise involving the Regularity Axiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am not sure how to proceed with the following question and would appreciate some help:

**Let $A,B$ and $C$ be sets.Further suppose that $A\in B$ and $B \in C$.Using the Regularity Axiom show that $C \notin A$.**

**My attempt:**

Since $A \in B$ and $B \in C$ therefore $C:=${{$A$}} or equivalently {$A$}$\in C$.
By the regularity axiom, since $C \neq \emptyset$, then there exists an element $x$ such that $x \in C$ and $x \cap C= \emptyset$. With {$A$} being the only element in $C$,it follows that {$A$}$\cap C= \emptyset$. To prove that $C \notin A$, suppose instead that $C \in A$ and derive a contradiction.

With $C \in A$ and {$A$} $\in C$ then by the pairing axiom the set {$A,C$} exists and hence $A \cap${$A,C$}$=C$ and $C \cap${$A,C$}$=\emptyset$....i do not really know how to proceed...looking at other sets and pairing them up does not yield any contradiction for me...

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues to address.

> Since $A \in B$ and $B \in C$ therefore $C:=${{$A$}} or equivalently {$A$}$\in C$.

You seem to be assuming that $A$ is the *only* element of $B$ and that $B$ is the *only* element of $C.$ However, this has not been given.

> By the regularity axiom, since $C \neq \emptyset$, then there exists an element $x$ such that $x \in C$ and $x \cap C= \emptyset$.

Very true.

> With {$A$} being the only element in $C$,it follows that {$A$}$\cap C= \emptyset$.

Well, again, we don't actually know for sure that $\{A\}$ is an element of $C,$ though it is a subset of an element of $C.$

> To prove that $C \notin A$, suppose instead that $C \in A$ and derive a contradiction.

Ah! Now that's a good idea!

> With $C \in A$ and {$A$} $\in C$ then by the pairing axiom the set {$A,C$} exists and hence $A \cap${$A,C$}$=C$ and $C \cap${$A,C$}$=\emptyset$....i do not really know how to proceed...looking at other sets and pairing them up does not yield any contradiction for me...

Try showing that $\{A,B,C\}$ is a set.

Once that's done, from here, we can use Regularity to get our contradiction. By Regularity, one of $A,B,C$ must have empty intersection with $\{A,B,C\},$ but $C\in A,$ $A\in B,$ and $B\in C,$ so this is not possible.

We could proceed even more easily with a direct proof. We first prove that $\{A,B,C\}$ is a set. Next, since $A\in B$ and $B\in C,$ we must have that $A\cap\{A,B,C\}=\emptyset$ by Regularity, so in particular, $C\notin A.$

Comment: Thank you for your nice response ! Would the following be correct : Assuming that $C \in A$ and with {$A,B,C$}$\neq \emptyset $ then $A \cap ${A,B,C}$=C$.But by the regularity axiom, there exists an $x \in  ${$A,B,C$} with $x \cap ${$A,B,C$}$= \emptyset$...is this right so far? if it is ..what allows me to choose x=A and thereby conclude a contradiction? Thank you!

Comment: You're close. Rather, we can say that $C\in A\cap\{A,B,C\}.$ However, we're not done, yet! We still need to justify that $B\cap\{A,B,C\}$ and $C\cap\{A,B,C\}$ are non-empty, and that $\{A,B,C\}$ is even a set!

Comment: Thank you very much! Applying the pairing axiom on (i) $A$ with itself and (ii) $B$ and $C$ yield the following sets {$A,A$} and {$B,C$}.Collecting these two sets into a family F and applying the union axiom suggests the existence of a set that consists of all elements belonging to at least one set in F hence {$A,B,C$} is assured.Now the following hold : (i)$C \in A \cap$ {$A,B,C$} ; (ii)  $A \in B \cap$ {$A,B,C$} ; (iii) $B \in C \cap$ {$A,B,C$}...By the regularity axiom one of A,B,C must be disjoint from the set {$A,B,C$}...but (i)-(iii) seem to be non empty!

Comment: Nicely done! I've edited my answer to lead you in that direction, and to pose an alternative to proof by contradiction.

Comment: Ahhh...thank you Cameron! There are truely patient people on this website!

Comment: We can but try!